# Is this how to get a refresh token using msal-node library?

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks, msal.js

I'm using the msal nodejs library. I have the following code

```
const ouathClient = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);

const tokenRequest = {
   code: request.query.code,
   scopes: process.env.OUTLOOK_OAUTH_SCOPES.split(','),
   redirectUri: process.env.DOMAIN_NAME + "/outlook/oauth/redirect",
   accessType: "offline"
};

const response = await ouathClient.acquireTokenByCode(tokenRequest);

const accessToken = response.accessToken;
const refreshToken = () => {
const tokenCache = ouathClient.getTokenCache().serialize();
const refreshTokenObject = (JSON.parse(tokenCache)).RefreshToken
const refreshToken = refreshTokenObject[Object.keys(refreshTokenObject)[0]].secret;
                return refreshToken;
            }
const tokens = {
   accessToken,
   refreshToken: refreshToken()
}
```

IS this how to get the refresh token from the msal-node library? I created an app that connects doctors and patients. I want patients to be able to book time on a doctor's outlook calendar. I need to get access to the doctor's outlook account. I can use the access token to get access to his calendar, but that expires.

How do I refresh the token after some time?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this how to get the refresh token from the msal-node library?

I'm not sure if that will work.  It looks like it will but you will still need to handle the actual refresh process once you have the token.  You may be able to use the `.acquireTokenByRefreshToken()` method of the ConfidentialClientApplication object, documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/msal-node/clientapplication?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-msal-node-clientapplication-acquiretokenbyrefreshtoken), but according to the documentation that is not the way Microsoft intends this library to be used, and if you rely on this kind of unsupported workflow, your code is susceptible to unexpectedly breaking if Microsoft changes anything.

> How do I refresh the token after some time?

In msal-node, the developer is not intended to do this themselves.  See [this github issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2836) for a discussion.  The library caches the tokens it receives, and you are intended to use them like this:

```
const someUserHomeAccountId = "Enter_User_Home_Account_Id";

const msalTokenCache = cca.getTokenCache();
const account = await msalTokenCache.getAccountByHomeId(someUserHomeAccountId);

const silentTokenRequest = {
    account: account,
    scopes: ["user.read"],
};

cca.acquireTokenSilent(silentTokenRequest).then((response) => {
    // do something with response
}).catch((error) => {
    // catch and handle errors
});
```

In this example (which is just copied from [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-node/docs/caching.md) very informative link) `cca` is the equivalent of your `oauthClient` variable.

By default, the token caching just occurs in memory.

Unfortunately, this is not appropriate for production applications, because the in-memory caching will only persist the token data for the lifetime of the MSAL instance, which means you will lose your tokens if the process ever restarts.  And if your server runs as multiple processes, they must share memory.

The caching is configured when you create the PublicClientApplication or ConfidentialClientApplication object. `cache` is an optional property of the [Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/msal-node/configuration?view=azure-node-latest) object that the client constructor takes in.  [The page](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-node/docs/caching.md) where I took the above example code from has a detailed discussion of how to implement your own caching solution that matches the protocol of the msal-node library.

There is an [official extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-node-extensions) library ([github repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/extensions/msal-node-extensions) has better docs) that has a solution to persist the cache to disk, but its intended purpose is PublicClientApplications.

For ConfidentialClientApplication instances running on a server, the best solution is to implement an L1/L2 cache where the L2 is a distributed store like Redis ([source](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/High-availability#pro-active-token-renewal)).  For something slightly simpler (only have the currently served user's tokens in memory), you can go to the [msal-node-samples](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-node-samples) and look at the ExpressTestApp example, which implements persistent caching with Redis.

Comment: i wish i could give you more than one up vote, thanks for the answer!